# Multi-Tenant App with multiple customer instance using shared credentials

Tags: architecture, entity-framework-4.1, saas, multi-tenant

I have searched around SO and other sights for help on how I might go about doing this.  I see many who recommend not doing it but I have legitimate and simple reasons why customers would want to.

**So here is what I am trying to do:**

I have a multi-tenant application with a common framework for managing the multi-tenant aspects of the application like data storage locations etc.  Each tenant will have “x” number of users that can access the tenant’s account.  However, each tenant can have multiple instances tied to their account.  For instance, the tenant may have a production instance and a test or dev instance as well.  Each instance has a one-to-one relationship to an isolated database.  It makes the most sense to me that I would store login credentials at the framework level against the tenant information and not in each individual instance as this would increase the number of usernames and passwords exponentially.

The design is fairly simple, there is a Tenant object which would have a collection of users and a collection of instances.  There would be an additional cross-reference object which would authorize users to access specific instances.  For instance, I may only allow a majority of the tenant users to access the production instance but for system admins they would have full access to all instances.

**The part I am hung up on is this:**

The user information stored across all instances should really only contain the basics like username and password because the details like Name, Phone number, etc. should all reside in the instance specific database.  More importantly the users will have a one-to-many relationship to another entity in each instance, be it an employee, person or contact object.

**My question then becomes:**

Based on the design I have what is the easiest way to link the objects (user and employee) across the models (framework, instance)?  More important, how do I keep data changes or modifications in sync across all instances, or should I even worry about that?

I would really appreciate any feedback anyone can offer, especially if you have tackled a problem like this already or have experience with this type of model.  I’m pretty set on the existing design as it has to work this way to meet customer requirements, I need to make the technology work for the requirements.

Thanks for your expertise!

Brent

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like there are sort of three interconnected things here, even though the question revolves around just one:

1. How does the data get stored in the database?
2. How do you ensure each user has access to only the instances to which they have rights?
3. How do you map the data to objects for use in code?

There are probably several ways to solve each one, but here's what I'd do:

**How does the data get stored in the database?**

Since you have one database per tenant-instance of the application (each "environment" - production, test, etc. would be a tenant-instance) and you have data that pertains to all of them, I would store the "common" data in a separate database, too.

Let's call that database the SystemConfiguration database. In that, you'd have:

- The list of all tenants in the system.
- The list of each instance's global configuration settings (e.g., database name, service endpoints, etc.), with each instance mapped to a tenant.
- The list of all users in the system, each mapped to a tenant (assuming a single user can't cross tenants... which could be complex, but not impossible).
- A mapping of users to the IDs of each instance each user has access to.

Splitting this SystemConfiguration database off as its own thing means you don't have to try to keep common user info synchronized anywhere. If there is per-instance user info (e.g., user settings or something), that'd go in the instance database, but name, password hash, etc. all goes in that central database.

Technically you could partition this in other ways, like having a separate user database, too, and only keeping tenant/system config in the SystemConfiguration database, but this at least gives you the idea.

If a tenant decides to leave, it would be pretty easy to query out any information related to the specific tenant and export it from the SystemConfiguration database. There shouldn't be a lot compared to the amount of tenant-specific data in the instance databases.

**How do you ensure each user has access to only the instances to which they have rights?**

I think claims-based authentication/authorization would make this problem a lot simpler. If you're not familiar with claims, the idea is that rather than have a static list of "roles" a user is in, you have a dictionary of name/value pairs associated with each user. The dictionary is the user's "claim set" and each name/value pair is a "claim." The benefit over roles is that the value can be anything, including a list.

Users, upon authenticating, would be issued a set of claims including their username, their first/last names, and the list of instances they have access to.

After that, it's a matter of simply checking the user's claims against the current instance's ID. If the authenticated user doesn't have access to that instance, block them.

Bringing it back to the data storage - generating the set of claims from that SystemConfiguration database would be a trivial query.

For more on claims-based identity and how to use Windows Identity Foundation to get that working in your application, check out [*Programming Windows Identity Foundation* by Vittorio Bertocci](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627185). It's a good book... and it's pretty much the only book on WIF.

**How do you map the data to objects for use in code?**

At this point, it's more about the view you want into the data from your code than it is about the structure of the data storage. If you want a Tenant object to have an IEnumerable<User> in it, that's all just futzing with the ORM of your choice.

I might suggest wrapping operations, at least around the SystemConfiguration database, with a service contract so if you change the data underneath, you can tweak the ORM at the service tier rather than your consuming code. Interfaces!

Anyway, the point here is that I'd not try to base the data storage necessarily on the way you consume the data.

Finally, if you need user or tenant information in your instances, you'll end up having some queries talk to the SystemConfiguration database and some talk to the tenant-instance database. That's OK. As long as you use a globally-unique identifier for everything, you can tie a user from the one database to some setting or value in another, just by ID. Referential integrity is a little harder to maintain, but it's easier than maintaining data synchronization across a bunch of instance databases.

This may be another reason to wrap things in services. For example, if you have a "UserSettings" service, your contract might ask for the tenant-instance ID and the user ID, and return the list of settings. Behind the scenes, the service could query data from SystemConfiguration, map it to the appropriate instance database, and return a merged dataset - all transparent to the calling code. On the other hand, you don't get that nice "Update()" method that some ORMs give you when you just change values on the objects and want to commit the changes. It's a trade-off on whether you want to manhandle the ORM into compliance to get that to happen.

Comment: Travis, I have already gone the route you mentioned with the first portion of your answer, the second is a great suggestion and once we get into securing the first set of services I'll take a look into that.  The last section really helped the most. My biggest trouble has been mapping data between the config and instance databases.  For instance, my user may be an employee and if my app allows them to enter expenses I want to be able to perform that mapping between a user and an employee to further restrict things. I'm pretty much on-board with just referencing GUIDs instead of syncing data.

Comment: I think referencing GUIDs will make it pretty straightforward. Whether you keep track of user access rights (beyond which instances each user can get to) in the central DB or in each instance is up to you; just lay a service interface down on top of it to unify the data for the consumer (e.g., when you're generating claims). Bam! Done. Glad I could be of assistance.

Comment: Ha ha, yea I'm finding when building a SaaS scalable app you really have to have an entire framework built to manage all of these small details and basically "host" your app. If only it was Bam! Done! Thanks again, I think I just needed someone else to say it was ok to reference GUIDs back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

**Rewrite:**

[Looks like my original answer was off-target, and that it's roughly what you have anyway. So...]

> > how do I keep data changes or modifications in sync across all instances, or should I even worry about that?

Do you have a requirement that requires you to keep them in sync, or any other driver?  If not... 
Assuming you do, you need to decide what you're going to synchronize against; what's the single source of truth.

A [Publish / Subscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe) or [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) type approach might be what you're after.

- Instances "publish" changes to the central system which the other instances pick up either during their normal life-cycle or ad-hoc based on an event / notification issued by the central system.
- Or a similar but decentralized approach where changes are broadcast to all interested parties at once (much harder I think, and with a new set of problems).

Comment: The primary reason for splitting the data out between the centralized store and instance is for recovery and backups purposes, in addition to making it very easy to dump customer data if they decide to leave.  I am already using a central store because the application is actually just a collection of web services being used by other apps. The part I'm struggling with is how to stitch/map the data across the models.